# Windows 8 missing text buttons in sub menus

Tags: windows-8

It took me a while to realize that there were even buttons that were "missing" I just thought windows 8 was hiding them for "usability". But apparently they are there there is just something wrong with the text?

Here is one example:

[image: http://imgur.com/udo1xNT]

This is in the uninstall window. note the blue box my mouse is hovering over next to "oragnize". If my mouse does not hover over it it is fully grey the and invisible.

There are other instances of this like in the add a device button is missing in the devices window.

How can I change this?

Comment: This computer on a domain?

Comment: No it is not on a domain.

Comment: The user that is logged in, in the screenshot, is a normal user or administrator?

Comment: Administrator login.

Comment: Is it the same if you log in as a different/new user?  Have you ran an `SFC` yet?

Comment: I have not tried either yet. I never used SFC before I will try it out. I will check soon as a different user.